# aframe: error in passing data to template under jade

Tags: aframe

I am using jade (pug) to dynamically create the required HTML pages. This includes creating of the aframe tags. When using kframe template components I am getting an error.

```
a-scene(embedded)
  a-assets
    script#boxesTemplate(type='text/x-jade-template')
      a-box(color="${color1}")
  a-entity(template='src: #boxesTemplate;', data-color1="blue", position="1 0 1")
  a-entity(template='src: #boxesTemplate;', data-color1="red", position="3 0 2")
```

The generated HTML tags look OK. However, the javascript console shows:

```
THREE.Color: Unknown color ${color1}
```

Any ideas why this occurs?. Thanks.

Raj

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not exactly what you like, but this 2 examples work for me:

```
a-assets
  script#boxesTemplate1(type="text/x-html-template").
    <a-box color="${box}" position="-1 0 -5"></a-box>
  script#boxesTemplate2(type="text/x-nunjucks-template").
    <a-box color="{{box}}" position="1 0 -5"></a-box>

a-entity(template="src: #boxesTemplate1" data-box="red")
a-entity(template="src: #boxesTemplate2" data-box="blue")
```

Maybe the type attribute of the template define the syntax of 'vars'. Maybe text/x-jade-template conflicts with the entire file.

Also, in a html file (not jade file) this works:

```
<a-scene>
  <script id="boxesTemplate3" type="text/x-jade-template">
    a-box(color="#{box}" position="0 1 -5")
  </script>
</a-assets>
<a-entity template="src: #boxesTemplate3" data-box="green"></a-entity>
```

¡saludos!

Comment: Thanks. Yes the problem was in the type.